# How to find the most recent associations created between two objects with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `user` model, a `movie` model and this association in user.rb (I use has_many :through because there are other associations between these two models):

> has_many :has_seens
>   has_many :movies_seen, :through => :has_seens, :source => :movie

I'm trying to get an array of the ten most recent `has_seens` associations created.

For now, the only solution I found is to crawl through all the users, creating an array with every user.has_seens found, then sort the array by has_seen.created_at and only keep the last 10 items… Seems like a heavy operation.

Is there a better way?

Kevin

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you're using the `Movie` model as the join table as specified by the `:source` option? Generally you use the `:has_many :through` association when you want a separate join model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by adding an `:order` clause to the `has_many :has_seens` association to order them by the creation date. Then use an association extension to define a method on the association itself:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :has_seens, :order => 'created_at DESC' do
    def recent(count=10)
      all(:limit => count)
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can use `user.has_seens.recent` to get the most recent ten movies seen. Optionally, pass in a different count e.g. `user.has_seens.recent(25)`.

Incidentally, I think that `viewings` is a less awkward association name than `has_seens`!

---

**Edit**: Personally, I would arrange things with a `Viewing` join model, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :viewings
  has_many :movies, :through => :viewings
end

class Viewing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie

  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'

  # Recent n viewings for any user  
  named_scope :recent, lambda { |count| { :limit => count }} 
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :viewings
  has_many :users, :through => :viewings
end
```

I've used a default scope on the `Viewing` model, but you could specify the ordering on the associations if viewings should be ordered by some other attribute other than creation date by default.

Now you can do:

```
# 10 most recent viewings for everyone
recent = Viewing.recent(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "recent" method is helpful, but I already managed to get the ten most recent has_seens of a specific user. I'm more trying to get the ten most recent has_seens from the database, between all the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using find:

```
HasSeen.find(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10)
```

You can use a named_scope (inside HasSeen model) like this:

```
named_scope :recent, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 10
```

and call `HasSeen.recent`.

If you are looking for the users, an easy (but not most efficient, I just don't know exactly how to do the join) way to do it is `recent_users = HasSeen.recent.map { |h| h.user }`

If the latter is what you are looking for, post a comment and I'll clean it up into a named_scope for the users model.